# My program use only 25% of cpu power

Tags: performance, cpu, cpu-usage

My program with single thread uses only 25% of CPU with 2 cores (intel i5-3210M). Why not 50% (one core)? Program is being tested on macbook pro with windows 7 64. I think that problem is hyper-threading and because of this program uses only one logical core (25% of cpu power). How can I give more CPU power to my program?
It's important for me because this program works with big set of data and it takes about 30 hours to finish calculations.

Comment: "How can I give more CPU power to my programm?" You might need to share some more information about your program, e.g. what language, a working sample of what you have so far - we don't need all your logic, just an idea of how it works.

Comment: Your program isn't *really* using 25% of available processing power because you don't have four physical cores; you have two physical cores, with two "virtual" cores (due to hyper-threading being enabled).  The CPU usage estimate is therefore skewed; whatever program you're using may *report* 25% CPU usage, but it's really closer to 50% (you're pegging 1 of 2 cores, not 1 of 4).  Enabling hyper-threading doesn't magically double your computing potential; the "hyper threads" show up as discrete CPUs for compatibility reasons, not because you can perform double the workload.  Keep that in mind.

Comment: Of course I tested my program on small set of model data. And program works correct. Now I'm testing the algorithm rathen then code. I know that the best way is using multi-threading but it is another question.

Comment: @Mike Strobel Thank you for the answer! I understand that "hyper-threading doesn't magically double your computing potential" but I thought it reduces computing potential twice for single-thread application (to 25% instead of 50%).

Comment: @maxibystro It doesn't do that; that's my point.  Those usage estimates are bogus.  They allocate 25% each to two "virtual" CPUs which have relatively little computing potential.  You're not using 1/4 of your computing potential just because Task Manager says so.  You're really using closer to 1/2 (50%).  Ignore the numbers.  If it makes you feel better, disable hyper-threading so it *says* you're using 50%, but it's not going to make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is expectable as you said with your CPU(which has 4 logical processors). You can search for the ways of transforming your program in order to use more than one threads. I can recommend you to search for "parallel programming", "concurrent programming","multi-threading". if you are using MS VC++ PPL library is so easy to use..OpenMP is a more prowerful tool which is available in Linux also. There are lots more ways and libraries for this issue but you need to choose it according to your OS, compiler, environment, programming language and your problem.

However, the easiest solution is to run it on a desktop machine with a better CPU and cross your fingers to get the results as quick as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> This program uses only one logical core (25% of cpu power). How can I give more CPU power to my programm? ...this programm works with big set of data ...  it takes about 30 hours to finish calculations.

Divide up your data set into (at least) 4 separate pieces. With that much data, you want to think in terms of indexes into the data instead of copying data elements to 4 separate structures. Create a separate thread for each segment of your data, and have that thread only process one segment. You may need to set a processor affinity for your threads.

If the data streams, or must be processed in order, think in terms of *queing* elements for processing, where individual threads will then dequeue and process each item. This works well when the enqueue operation is relatively fast compared to processing an item, and can be done by a single master thread, while each dequeue/processing operation is more expensive.

Choosing the correct number of threads is tricky. Modern CPUs and operating systems are designed to switch tasks from time to time. This will always be an expensive operation, but the scheduler will want to do something else every so often, even if your process may seem like the best candidate. Therefore, you can often get the best throughput by overloading your CPUs to a small extent, such that you may want two or three threads per logical cpu. One way to manage this is through use the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) object.

Comment: Thank you but I know how to use multi-threading. Only what I wanted to know is why process uses only 25% of cpu power (not 50%). And now I understand that one physical core works for 100% although task manager reports about 25%.